# How to convert Octet-Stream to a pdf file via LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, applicationoctet-stream

I am trying to convert the OCTET-Stream to a PDF file and download it. Currently, I am receiving this stream via IP(Vlocity) into an LWC. In my LWC JS, I have the following code snippet.

```
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        var blob = new Blob([(content)], {'type':contentType});
        var href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = href;
        a.setAttribute('download', filename);
        a.click();
```

But this snippet is downloading a file that is not valid. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!